# Logged in As or Welcome?

Tags: accounts, tone-of-voice

At the top of a normal webpage, is it better to say:

`Welcome, Username`

or

`Logged in as Username?`

Which one is better for the end user?

EDIT:

Or is better just to display there username, and profile picture, or just the picture, or just the username.

Comment: This seems like a question with no correct answer. It always depends on your site and how you otherwise address your users.

Comment: What is a 'normal' webpage?

Comment: The "normal" part was added by kontur in an edit, so you would have to ask him for that. :)

Comment: According to http://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/45750/revisions that's not true.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Wordpress presents a "_Howdy, [Username]_".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

How about just Username ?

Just see how many sites including Stack Exchange, Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc don't show any other kind of salutation. They just show the username, which is hyperlinked to suggest that further profile information can be viewed by navigating to this link.

Comment: I actually can't believe that I didn't think of this before! :) I believe that this could be a better way to do it. Nevertheless, the discussion can still continue!

Comment: @AmarH-V if this reply has helped you, kindly upvote the same too.

Comment: I can't upvote yet because of my low reputation :( I wish it would carry over from SO, because I most certainly would up vote your answer!

Answer (score 7):

For me this would entirely depend on the context.

If your definition of "username" was a user's first and last name, then "welcome..." would be more polite than "logged in as..."; on the contrary, if your "username" was just something the user used to log in, "logged in as..." would make more sense than "welcome...", as otherwise you're welcoming the user's username and not necessarily their identity.

That said, if a user had been logged in for more than 5 minutes, would you really still want to display "welcome..."?

"Logged in as..." is a more of a reference to the user's account than a greeting to the user.

Answer (score 2):

I was inclined to say Welcome at first, but then I noticed you're using the username. I think if you're still wondering whether it should be Logged in or Welcome, then Logged in as  would make sense. Welcome would work better if it was Welcome .

Logged in as admin_91

Welcome John

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters. Both indicate for the user that s/he is logged in (actually it's **username (and preferably an avatar, for better visual indication)** that indicates that user is logged in. I usually choose ***Welcome, username***, as "welcome" it's more welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to offer another perspective: If security is important (such as for a banking site), I would prefer the term "logged in" because it explicitly indicates an open session, whereas "Welcome" simply implies that the website *recognizes* you, perhaps based on the last time you used it.